# How to use pattern recognition on graphs/charts?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, neural-network, pattern-recognition

I can create time-series graphs from data (charts) as images in C#. One might be moving average of a measured value, say 100 pixels by 100 pixels, time on X, value on Y.

I only train with graphs of values that give a desired (or undesired) result. This means I have lots of 10k images of success that I can use for training a NN.

The idea is to look at a current graph and establish a % match against the training data (many successful images either compiled/summed, averaged, etc. A high % match is likely the same situation exists now as with previous successes.

But I cannot figure out:

Q: How to compare images, or more basically, how to *load* a current image to test against in a trained NN. Do I really need 10,000 input nodes?!

There has to be a better way.

Right now I'm trying to make Encog/C# work for the image recognition/matching. There seems to be a lot of research in OCR, where a hard yes/no is made on input data, but not much at all about a 'fuzzy' match to the training data...

Comment: Firstly, try down sampling the image using mip-maping or something. This way you will have a bit more manageable input nodes.
If you prepare the training set well, it should work.
Try openCV, you might like it.

Comment: @SouradeepNanda, I have not heard of either of these (MIP-mapping or OpenCV), so I will take your advice and look into them! Thank you!